# `os.symlink` vs `ln -s`

Tags: python, linux, bash, symlink

I need to create a symlink for every item of dir1 (file or directory) inside `dir2`. `dir2` already exists and is not a symlink. In Bash I can easily achieve this by:

```sh
ln -s /home/guest/dir1/* /home/guest/dir2/
```

But in python using `os.symlink` I get an error:

```
>>> os.symlink('/home/guest/dir1/*', '/home/guest/dir2/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 17] File exist
```

I know I can use `subprocess` and run `ln` command. I don't want that solution.

I'm also aware that workarounds using `os.walk` or `glob.glob` are possible, but I want to know if it is possible to do this using `os.symlink`.

Comment: I *think* `os.symlink` is a mere wrapper of the respective system call (well, more or less) and therefore wouldn't provide the same semantics you get from a full-fledged utility using that system call.

Comment: What is the reason for the "I want to do this using `os.symlink`" requirement? If the right thing to do is a `for` loop over a `glob`, why don't you want to do the right thing?

Comment: @abarnert I will do that if I have to. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it with `os.symlink`. I thought it would provide everything `ln -s` does, but turns out it does not.

Comment: @jurgenreza: You're still missing the key point: what you're looking for isn't something `ln -s` does, it's something _the shell_ does.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: It's a tiny bit more complicated (see [the source](5f4d7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l7199)), but only a tiny bit; basically,  it ultimately calls `symlink`, `symlinkat`, or `CreateSymbolicLinkW`. And the semantics are clearly designed to match POSIX `symlink` even if that's not what it ends up using.

Comment: @abarnert: yep, that's what my "well, more or less" was aimed at.

Comment: @abarnert oh ok, I think I got it now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: I wasn't correcting you, so much as taking away any doubt left by your "I _think_" prefix.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`os.symlink`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) creates a single symlink.

`ln -s` creates multiple symlinks (if its last argument is a directory, and there's more than one source). The Python equivalent is something like:

```
dst = args[-1]
for src in args[:-1]:
    os.symlink(src, os.path.join(dst, os.path.dirname(src)))
```

So, how does it work when you do `ln -s /home/guest/dir1/* /home/guest/dir2/`? Your *shell* makes that work, by turning the wildcard into multiple arguments. If you were to just `exec` the `ln` command with a wildcard, it would look for a single source literally named `*` in `/home/guest/dir1/`, not all files in that directory.

The Python equivalent is something like (if you don't mind mixing two levels together and ignoring a lot of other cases—tildes, env variables, command substitution, etc. that are possible at the shell):

```
dst = args[-1]
for srcglob in args[:-1]:
    for src in glob.glob(srcglob):
        os.symlink(src, os.path.join(dst, os.path.dirname(src)))
```

You can't do that with `os.symlink` alone—either part of it—because it doesn't do that. It's like saying "I want to do the equivalent of `find . -name foo` using `os.walk` without filtering on the name." Or, for that matter, I want to do the equivalent of `ln -s /home/guest/dir1/* /home/guest/dir2/` without the shell globbing for me."

The right answer is to use `glob`, or `fnmatch`, or `os.listdir` plus a regex, or whatever you prefer.

Do *not* use `os.walk`, because that does a *recursive* filesystem walk, so it's not even close to shell `*` expansion.

Comment: `ln` is ln [target] [link], how can there be several targets as you describe? I think you mean several links linking to one target?

Answer (score 17):

`*` is a shell extension pattern, which in your case designates "all files starting with `/home/guest/dir1/`".

But it's your *shell's role to expand this pattern* to the files it matches. Not the `ln` command's.

But `os.symlink` is not a shell, it's an OS call - hence, it doesn't support shell extension patterns. You'll have to do that work in your script.

To do so, you can use `os.walk`, or `os.listdir`. As indicated in the other answer, the appropriate call will depend on what you want to do. (`os.walk` wouldn't be the equivalent of `*`)

---

To convince yourself: run this command on an Unix machine in your terminal: `python -c "import sys; print sys.argv" *`. You'll see that it's the shell that's doing the matching.

Comment: +1 for the experiment about the globbing. Keep in mind, however, that thw Windows shell (cmd.exe) does *not* do this before passing it to the invoked program.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Well, to be fair, Windows doesn't come with `ln`. And MSVCRT (their libc) comes with a hack to simulate shell globbing on `argv` either before your `main` starts, or when you explicitly ask it to, and I'm pretty sure most ports of Unix programs will either use that or something equivalent (e.g., whatever Cygwin does).

Comment: @0xC0000022L I must confess checking whether this worked on Windows didn't cross my mind - will update!

Comment: @abarnert: well, they call it `mklink`, just like they call what's known in the *nix world as `mkdir` simply `md` in the Windows world.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: But `mklink` doesn't have the same syntax as `ln`. In particular, `mklink` cannot take a list of sources and link them all into a directory; it takes a single source and a single target.

Comment: @abarnert: true point. Thought you were referring to the lack of a tool as a whole.

Answer (score 9):

As suggested by @abarnert it's the shell that recognizes `*` and replaces it with all the items insside dir1. Therefore I think using `os.listdir` is the best choice:

```
for item in os.listdir('/home/guest/dir1'):
    os.symlink('/home/guest/dir1/' + item, '/home/guest/dir2/' + item)
```

Comment: I suggest using `os.path.join` rather than `+`.